# Angular 2/4 - showing list and not tracking changes on it

Tags: javascript, performance, angular, typescript, ngfor

Is it possible to show a list of strings, and do not track changes on them? (I'm having performance issues).

I'm getting list of languages from REST API and then generating dropdowns of languages dynamically using *ngFor. App starts to get slow when I have 10+ dropdowns (10 dropdowns * 200 languages = 2000 items to watch).

The solution would be not to track changes on my languages list, as it's never going to change, but there's nothing documented on that.

**Code**

Controller
`langs: string[] = ['English', 'German', 'Spanish', ...];`

View
`<select ...>
    <option *ngFor="lang of langs">{{lang}}</option>
</select>`

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. I assume you have some function binding somewhere or similar.

Comment: Edited my issue

Comment: And `langs` is a static property in your code that causes performance issues like the code shown in your question, or do you get it from a function call?

Comment: the problem is that I'm generating lot of lists (select inputs) with lot of languages (options). I'm having performance issues because Angular tracking changes on every one of them. So what I'm asking is if it is possible to show the list of languages and do not track changes on it (langs property)

Comment: I doubt that tracking changes causes this. Please add more code that shows how `ngFor` gets the values passed.

Comment: Perhaps you just need to switch to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` like mentioned in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8382

Comment: As tracking has already been discussed, I suggest a performance audit. You can do this using the profiling tool (in Chrome) to identify what script is causing your performance issues. This can be found in the 'Performance' section of Chrome Dev Tools.

If you identify any irregularities, feel free to post here and we can discuss further and get this issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

We can help Angular to track which items added or removed by providing a `trackBy` function. The `trackBy` function takes the index and the current item as arguments and needs to return the unique identifier for this item.

Now when you change the collection, Angular can track which items have been added or removed according to the unique identifier and create or destroy only the things that changed. Check the documentation here: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: Tried to use this, but this function still gets called lot of times and this decreases performance